# Remove first value from object

Tags: jquery, json, object

I have this object:

```
var i = $("[name~=article]").map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

What I get is something like this:

```
var i = [
    [{
        "invoice": 1,
        "article": "ff",
        "qty": "0"
    }, {
        "invoice": 1,
        "article": "Coca Cola",
        "qty": "33"
    }, {
        "invoice": 1,
        "article": "Fanta",
        "qty": "2"
    }],
];
```

What i need is to remove first value entire to get something like this

```
var i = [{
    "invoice": 1,
    "article": "Coca Cola",
    "qty": "33"
}, {
    "invoice": 1,
    "article": "Fanta",
    "qty": "2"
}];
```

I always need to remove the first, and must change structure of the object?

Comment: but structure has been changed

Comment: Do you want to change `[[{` to `[{` or do you want to remove `"article": "ff"` entry?

Comment: please take a look at new i

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = $("[name~=article]:not(:first)").map(function(v,i) {
    return this.value;
}).get()[0];
```

Comment: This is ok, but structure i want to change?

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not pay much attention to that detail... Editing my answer

Comment: [[{"invoice":1,"article":"Coca Cola","qty":"33"},{"invoice":1,"article":"Coca Cola"}],[{"invoice":1,"article":"Fanta","qty":"5"},{"invoice":1,"article":"Coca Cola","qty":"33"}]]

Comment: Have you added the `[0]` after `get()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62344/discussion-between-gorostas-and-laruiss).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on the result

```
var i = $("[name~=article]").map(function() {
          return $(this).val()
        }).get()[0]
          .splice(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use slice like

```
var i = $("[name~=article]").slice(1).map(function () {
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
 i = i.shift();
 i.shift();
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/0mfdv7wg/

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift